# Add flextable into a given position at word document

Tags: r, bookmarks, flextable, officer

I am trying to add a flextable to a word document at a given bookmark.

I have created a flextable which I can display correctly and also insert it at the word document, though I want it to be included at the bookmark "Tabla33" position

Though I got the following error.

```
Error in xpath_search(x$node, x$doc, xpath = xpath, nsMap = ns, num_results = 1) : 
  Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=10].
```

Here is the code I am using.

```
    BKM<-read_docx( "myword_document.docx") %>%
      officer::cursor_reach("Table33");    doc<-read_docx( "myword_document.docx") %>%
      body_replace_flextable_at_bkm( BKM,  value = Tabla33, align = "center")
```

Comment: It seems you are not providing a "bookmark id" ("Table33") but an object of class rdocx. You should use  `doc<-read_docx( "myword_document.docx") %>%
  body_replace_flextable_at_bkm( "Table33",  value = Tabla33, align = "center")` instead

Comment: Thanks David for your prompt response. I tried your suggestions and got the following error: Error: bookmark "Tabla33" does not end in the same paragraph (or is on the whole paragraph) `doc<-read_docx( "myword_document.docx") %>% body_replace_flextable_at_bkm( "Tabla33", value = Tabla33, align = "center")`

Comment: Then your bookmark is not ending in the paragraph where it starts... read the first paragraph of this manual https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/reference/body_replace_text_at_bkm.html